# Cast the two first words of a column to another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID'   : ['T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home'] })

                ID
0   T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home
1   Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home
```

I want to take the two first words from each row and cast them to a new column

**Expected outcome:**

```
    New_id                       ID
0   T1002_T5006,         Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home
1   Go for walk_T5007,   Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
df1['New_id']= df1["ID"].str.split(',').str.join(sep=" ")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the dataframe `df` looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home', 'Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home']})

[Out]:
                                     ID
0        T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home
1  Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home
```

Then the following will do the work

```
df['New_id'] = df['ID'].str.split(',').str[:2].str.join('_')

[Out]:
                                     ID              New_id
0        T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home        T1002_ T5006
1  Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home  Go for walk_ T5007
```

**Notes:**

- `df['ID']` selects the column ID from the dataframe `df`
- `.str.split(',')` splits the string by the comma
- `str[:2]` takes the first two words
- `.str.join('_')` joins the strings with an underscore between them. One could leave it as follows `.str.join('')` and, with that, the output would be

  ```
                                       ID             New_id
  0        T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home        T1002 T5006
  1  Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home  Go for walk T5007
  ```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df["New_id"] = df['ID'].map(lambda x: '_'.join([i.strip() for i in x.split(',')[:2]]))

    ID                                      New_id
0   T1002, T5006, T5007, Stay home          T1002_T5006
1   Go for walk, T5007, T5007, Stay home    Go for walk_T5007
```